# Alinear a la derecha NAVBAR en bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quisiera alinear en *Bootstrap 4* el navegador hacia la derecha.

Por defecto queda hacia la izquierda, lo intenté de varias maneras pero no pude, aca les dejo el código.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                EMPRESA
            </a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Caracteristicas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Planes</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
 <header>
```

Comment: Quieres todo alineado a la derecha incluso la imagen??? o imagen a la izquierda y menu a la derecha?

Comment: Como lo solucionaste ? estoy usando bootstrap 4 beta

Comment: @JosCars las respuestas no deben usarse para escribir comentarios (lee [answer] en el centro de ayuda). En la [respuesta de sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31629/250) puedes ver una solución usando Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 4):

lo solucione con este código

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Comment: `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">` Fue lo único que me sirvió pero me podrías explicar como funciona?

Comment: @EduardoHV, aunque esta respuesta puede solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido. Deberías añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace la línea de código que pones? ¿Dónde debería ir? ¿cómo solucionaría el problema? Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 2):

En la web [Bootstrap 4 NavBars](http://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/tutorial/bootstrap_navbars.cfm) en la seccion **Alignment** puedes ocupar estas clases `pull-*-left` o `.pull-*-right`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
<!-- Links -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ya intente con eso y no me funciona para alinearla a la derecha! copie y pegue tu mismo codigo.

Comment: Modificaste el pull-xs-right por el tamaño que desea?

Comment: Al parecer era un error de la version 4.0.0-alpha5, solo tuve que cambiarlo a la alpha4 y ya funciona normal! gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Comment: Perfecto, saludos